# Vertically aligning an image to the middle of a div

Tags: css

I could use some CSS helping getting a CSS to vertically align in the middle of a div.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="imageSet-container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="frame-title">Title Here</div>
        <div class="frame-image">
            <a href="xxxx"><img alt="" src="XXXXXX"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="frame-meta">
            <li>0 Comments</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

     XXX Multiple image-containers repeat here

</div>

.image-container {
 float: left;
 height: 250px;
 margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 250px;
}
.image-container .frame-image {
   height: 180px;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
.image-container .frame-image img {
    max-width:170px;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

I would like .frame-image img to be vertically aligned in the middle of .frame-image, but it's always on the top.

ideas?

Comment: Watch out for the quote you missed here: <div class="frame-title>Title Here</div>. It's missing right after class="frame-title. edit: Also, it's good practice to give img elements end tags, ie: <img src="herp" alt="derp" />

Comment: Thanks that was just an error introduced by asking the question.

Comment: You should use a table in such a case, or at least, a div with a td's display type (if you want to use plain CSS). Either case, it's a table feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use jax to set the top and left according to the div size:

```
img.left = div.width / 2 - img.width / 2
img.top = div.height / 2 - img.height / 2
```

Comment: JavaScript? Why can't this be all CSS?

Comment: it's really hard to get vertical center right in css especially since different browsers behave differently. if you're already using jQuery the impact should be minimal.

Comment: That[code]'s outright stupid...avoiding tables to use javascript instead?!

Comment: But, it will be delayed till the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a line-height of 180px to .image-container .frame-image seems to work

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving the parent fixed height, you can try to give padding to the child and as the upper and bottom margin will be the same, it will be in the middle of the container.